# Docker run does not deploy

Tags: docker

So we followed the Docker get started tutorial 
(https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/). The build works, the command

```
docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
```

works but when we go to http://localhost:4000, nothing is reached. We just followed the tutorial step by step but don't see anything.

Yes we also went to localhost:4001.
Is this perhaps something that has to do witht the message "system pool is not available on windows"?

Here's a screenshot of our docker output
[image: Console output]

Comment: Are you using docker-toolbox? What does `echo $DOCKER_HOST` show?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly talking about the issue that you've pointed out yourself, this is identified as an issue that can't be fixed for Windows.

Please try downgrading to version `1.12.x` so that these warnings do not pop-up anymore. This solution is found working for most of us.

```
level-info msg="Unable to use system certificate pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows"
```

Coming to the ***main*** issue that you're facing, which is as follows:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint objective_joliot
```

This says that the port 4000 is already in use on `Docker VM` or possibly on your system. You can either stop whatever is running on that port or change the port used in your `Docker` command.

To change to the external port 8080, use:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name objective_joliot nginx
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: The ports weren't in use, but we just installed a Ubuntu on virtualbox and Docker works decently there. Seems like it's a Windows issue

Comment: Ok, to some extent the issues was with Windows!